Is there a way to work with Apache gucamole's JSON Auth in the self compiled version?
I am trying to use a compiled version of guacamole client because I want to make some changes to the front end of the project.
I was able to compile the project can work with it normally, but the Encrypted JSON authentication does not seem to be working, when I was using the docker image of the guacamole client everything was working fine but the compiled version is working in a different way even tho it is the same version.
I made a bit of code that basically returns the JSON that will be stored in the GUAC_AUTH local storage variable and the link to the VM, the result of my code can be seen in this JSON:
{
      "link": "http://192.168.233.90:9040/guacamole/#/client/Z2l0AGMAanNvbg==",
      "GUAC_AUTH": {
            "authToken": "858056C32F92817445D215897B18A08EFEB257A29BDEA8638F5FBC20A17243DF",
            "username": "feef183c-4a29-42a2-985a-581f06f93135",
            "dataSource": "json",
            "availableDataSources": [
                  "postgresql",
                  "postgresql-shared",
                  "json"
            ]
      }
}

This works with the docker version of guacamole, but not the version I compiled.
I tried it with 3 different connections and they all worked with the docker version of guacamole.
The problem now is that it is not working with the version I compiled, Ill reiterate that I have not modified the code yet, I have also double checked that I'm using the 1.5.5 image and that the pom.xml in the compiled version says it is the 1.5.5 version as well. I have also confirmed that both version have the following logs showing the JSON extension is working.
16:13:29.027 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.g.extension.ExtensionModule -  - [json] "Encrypted JSON Authentication" (/tmp/guacamole-home.3hXieEXOMq/extensions/guacamole-auth-json.jar)
16:13:30.381 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.a.g.extension.ExtensionModule - [2] Binding AuthenticationProvider "org.apache.guacamole.auth.json.JSONAuthenticationProvider".
16:13:30.678 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.g.extension.ExtensionModule - Extension "Encrypted JSON Authentication" (json) loaded.

and I also checked that all the environment variables i added are the same.
The only difference in behavior i was able to find (besides my authentication not working) is that in my compiled version there is an additional variable in the local storage that never appears in my docker version, that being the GUAC_AUTH_TOKEN variable and that the following request fails in the compiled version:
POST http://192.168.233.90:9040/guacamole/api/tokens
SENT INFO
token=238FD7DDDAD9CF10EF6D1B1234E356C457A908D463B24AEFBA9F4EAB4F2617B2

RETURN INFO
{
    "message": "Invalid login",
    "translatableMessage": {
        "key": "APP.TEXT_UNTRANSLATED",
        "variables": {
            "MESSAGE": "Invalid login"
        }
    },
    "statusCode": null,
    "expected": [
        {
            "name": "username",
            "type": "USERNAME"
        }, {
            "name": "password",
            "type": "PASSWORD"
        }
    ],
    "patches": null,
    "type": "INVALID_CREDENTIALS"
}

I tried using the authToken shown in my request as the GUAC_AUTH_TOKEN but that also did not work.
After all of this I'm still not able to fix the issue or even figure out the source of the problem. If anyone has any idea on how to deal with this any help would be appreciated.
